# Mouseenter doesn't restore its variable after mousleave empties the variable

Tags: jquery

I am trying to display the description on mouseenter and and hides the description on `mouseleave`. 
The problem is I emptied my appended variable on `mouseleave`, but again when mouse is enter the variable is lost forever, it doesn't append its variable again.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){

                    $(".defList").css("display","none");

                    $("#1a").mouseenter(function(){
                        var defterm=$(".1b");

                        $(".slidingDiv dl").append(defterm);
                        $(".slidingDiv").css("left", 150);
                        $(".slidingDiv").css("top", 150);
                        $(".slidingDiv").fadeIn("fast");    

                        $("#1a").mouseleave(function(){
                            $(".slidingDiv").fadeOut("fast");
                            $(".slidingDiv dl").empty();
                        });     

                    });


                    $("#2a").mouseenter(function(){
                        var defterm=$(".2b");           
                        $(".slidingDiv dl").append(defterm);
                        $(".slidingDiv").css("left", 300);
                        $(".slidingDiv").css("top", 150);
                        $(".slidingDiv").show("fast");

                        $("#2a").mouseleave(function(){ 
                            $(".slidingDiv").fadeOut("fast");
                            $(".1b").empty();
                        });
                    });
            });
```

Comment: well you emptied it $(".1b").empty(); the next time you hover on #1a .1b is empty. If you never hover on #2a then it will work

Comment: what happend if you move the mouseleave function outside from the mouse enter function?

Comment: lets tart with why do u need to empty .b1 ?

Answer (score 0):

You are aiming to show/ hide something on mouseenter/houseleave.
Dont use javascript, use css  :hover

you can use css transitions  to animate the fade in/out.

please show the html and desired effect. Then we can help you with the css.

In any case, instead of empty(), do defterm.detach() this way the element will survive.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what CodeToad suggests or just cache the values and then reassign. Again, seems odd to "empty" it out. There are a lot of ways to tackle your situation. But curious why you want to empty it out. You can wrap it in a span, and just "hide" it. and then show when you want it.

```
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){

                $(".defList").css("display","none");
                var cache = {
                    '1b' : $('.1b'),
                    '2b' : $('.2b'),
                }
                $("#1a").mouseenter(function(){
                    $(".slidingDiv dl").append(cache['1b']);
                    $(".slidingDiv").css("left", 150);
                    $(".slidingDiv").css("top", 150);
                    $(".slidingDiv").fadeIn("fast");    

                    $("#1a").mouseleave(function(){
                        $(".slidingDiv").fadeOut("fast");
                        $(".slidingDiv dl").empty();
                    });     

                });


                $("#2a").mouseenter(function(){
                    $(".slidingDiv dl").append(cache['2b']);
                    $(".slidingDiv").css("left", 300);
                    $(".slidingDiv").css("top", 150);
                    $(".slidingDiv").show("fast");

                    $("#2a").mouseleave(function(){ 
                        $(".slidingDiv").fadeOut("fast");
                        $(".1b").empty();
                    });
                });
        });
```